# Nuget package push 403 error on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have created a visual studio class library. I want to send this to Nuget as a package. I used **Visual studio package manager** console.
The commans are like following:

- nuget spac hellonuget
- nuget pack hellonuget.nuspec
- nuget push hellonuget.1.0.0.nupkg -ApiKey *****

> this returned an error: nuget : Failed to process request. 'The
>   specified API key is invalid or does not have permission to access the
>   specified package.'.  At line:1 char:1
>   + nuget push hellonuget.1.0.0.nupkg
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Failed to proce...ied package.'. :String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

I tried second way. I tried these commands from windows CMD window. I created nuget package of HelloNuget.dll.

- D:\App\HelloNuget> nuget spac hellonuget.dll
- D:\App\HelloNuget> nuget pack hellonuget.nuspec
- D:\App\HelloNuget> nuget push hellonuget.1.0.0.nupkg -ApiKey *****

  Succesfully published the pack.

What is the problem about visual studio package manager?

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem and it was because i was using a name for the package that exists already . Once i changed the name of of the package to something unique it published perfectly.

Comment: All packages in my cache have unique name, the easiest way to achieve it is to concat package name and its version.

Comment: As long as the name of your package doesn't exist already in nuget database , you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with [DeveloperTools](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DeveloperTools)

The original intended name was `DevTools` but PSGallery was rejecting this name. I can only guess the real reason was a conflict with `PSDevTools` which is not the same. Once I changed the name into DeveloperTools, everything was fine.

I don't really understand why there is GUID in module manifests when PSGallery doesn't really care about this strong type identification.