# Not able to upload a Nuget Package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, api-key

So for the first time, I am creating nuget package for a .Net Framework Library and I want to upload it to the nuget server. I have followed this tutorial [Nuget Package Creation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPm9FsptuE8)
 and I have got my account created in Nuget and also I have created the API key and even the nuget package is ready in the solution folder. But when I run below command to push the package I get the API Key error.

[image]

Error: THe specifies API key is invalid or does not have the permission. But I just now created and account and the API key. Please guide me.

When I try to upload directly to Nuget Website I get below error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nuget package push 403 error on visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514453/nuget-package-push-403-error-on-visual-studio)

Comment: @RuiJarimba: I am trying to upload even via UI of nuget but I am not able to do so. I renamed file `.nupkg` to something unique but still I get the error. Why this error means "The package ID `Class Library1` does not exist. See the screenshot above.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Hard to tell what is your problem, keep looking on stackoverflow and google. I've seen a post somewhere where someone had issues with an older version of nuget. Which version are you using? Have you tried with one of the most recent ones?

Comment: I downloaded the most recent nuget.exe if thats what you mean.

Comment: Oh and maybe try with a different package id, not ClassLibrary1. Someone probably is already using that one. Add the full namespace to your nuget package/assembly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183089/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-rui-jarimba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following message might be displayed when a user tries to upload a package with the same id of another package (more info on [Unable to upload package](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/1839])):

> The package ID 'xxxxxxx' is not available

So, instead of using a generic default namespace and assembly name:

[image: Project properties with default namespace]

Consider using your own namespace, in order to avoid package ID conflicts. Package will be generated with the same name as the assembly name. Example:

[image: Project properties with custom namespace]

### Changing the package ID in .NET Standard Class Libraries

If you're using a .NET Standard Class Library you can change the package ID directly in the project properties > Package section:

[image: Project properties - Package section]

Please note that by default the package ID is the same as the Assembly Name.